# Regex for partial image link

Tags: c#, regex

I need to create a C# regex that finds the following match case: A string that starts with any number no matter how many digits ([0-9]*). Afterwards it follows a slash / and then it can contain any sequecence (*). It stops as it ends by .jpg.

So far this is what I have created without sucess:

```
 Regex oRegex = new Regex("^[0-9]*/*.(jpg)$");
```

Since I've kind of forgot about regular expressions, is there anyone here who could help me?

EDIT:

Example of wanted strings:

> 23/3-2131-3134SA-2FRT-3DD.jpg
>
> 566/FSFRT-D3566-DDDDSF.jpg

I've tried most of the regex answered in this question and so far no luck. This string is comming from an HTML response. I will leave an actual response with HTML:

> /home/app/app-api/uload.php on line <s>94</s>
> \n3/90C6D420-5B25-44CD-A57A-4A030D2762B0.jpg"

Comment: Does it really have to be a regex? See http://ideone.com/UU8n6b

Comment: What if string is `2A3/3-2131-3134SA-2FRT-3DD.jpg` your code will match it but does OP want that ? It is not clear tho.. at least to me.

Comment: @kuskmen the string will always start with a number.

Comment: Yes ,but is `2A3/3-2131-3134SA-2FRT-3DD.jpg`a valid match or not? and what you are trying to achieve cause by last edit it seems that you may have misunderstood what it needs to be done ...

Comment: Try `new Regex(@"^[0-9]+/.*\.jpg$", RegexOptions.Multiline)`. See my edited answer.

Comment: I've written on the beggining. I want to extract a string that starts with any number , followed by a slash, followed by anycharacter and ending with .jpg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding:

> A string that starts with any number no matter how many digits (`[0-9]*`). Afterwards it follows a slash `/` and then it can contain any sequecence (`*`). It stops as it ends by `.jpg`.

The point is that your `[0-9]*` does not enforce the must-have digit(s)-at-the-start requirement, as the `*` quantifier allows matching an empty string. Also, you allow no `/` in the string by using `/*`. Then, `.` is not quantified, while you want to match any 0+ chars up to the `.jpg`. So, you needed `.*` there. Then, the `.` must be escaped to match a literal `.`.

So, the regex you need is just

```
new Regex(@"^[0-9]+/.*\.jpg$", RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

The **`RegexOptions.Multiline`** flag will allow matching at the start of a *line*.

You are not using the `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` flag, so you want a case sensitive match. This check can be achieved with no regex:

```
s.EndsWith(".jpg") && Char.IsDigit(s[0]) && s.Contains("/")
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/UU8n6b). However, the position of the `/` is not being accounted for in the non-regex approach.

Answer (score 4):

It should be something like:

```
^\d+/.+\.jpg$
```

Explanation:

- `^` marks the beginning of a line in the sequence.
- `\d` marks a digit (shorthand for `[0-9]`).
- `.+` means at least one occurrence of any character.
- `\.jpg` marks the literal `.jpg` (the period needs to be escaped).
- `$` marks the end of the line in the sequence.

Comment: Does this match second string given as example ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you (1) mixed the star and the dot and (2) need to escape the slash:

```
Regex oRegex = new Regex("^[0-9]+\/.+(\.jpg)$");
```

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/mK8zK2/1

Comment: There is no need to escape the slash at all. The `*` with the first `[0-9]` makes the pattern match an empty string and it does not require a digit at the start.

Comment: True. Updated with a plus.

Comment: @Wiktor: I'm not sure which flavour .NET uses, but in PCRE and JavaScript, the backslash does seem to be required. Python-style, you can skip it.

Comment: Come on, .NET regex engine has its own engine. Regex101 does not even support it.

Comment: Ouch. So far for my moment of insanity :$

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to match that.

```
[0-9]*\/[a-zA-Z0-9_]*(\.jpg)
```

Comment: Can be improved:
`(\d*\/.*)\.jpg`

**\d** instead of [0-9]. **.** instead of [a-zA-Z0-9_].

I don't know why you would capture the *.jpg* group...